# Swift Combine collect values only while sink is busy

Tags: swift, combine

We have a Publisher which can publish new values `v` quickly but processing those values can be slow. This causes values to back up which we don't want. Having an array of multiple values `v` allows us to combine those into a single value. We cannot miss any published values.

We thus would like to collect values while sink is busy with `slowProcessing` and do nothing otherwise (i.e. go immediately to `slowProcessing` if the queue is currently free).

Due to the requirement of running `slowProcessing` immediately  we cannot buffer values using `buffer(size:prefetch:whenFull:)` or `collect(_:options:)`. As we cannot miss any values we cannot use `debounce(for:scheduler:options:)` or `throttle(for:scheduler:latest:)`

Is there a way to achieve this using Swift Combine?

```
private let snapshotQueue = DispatchQueue(
    label: "snapshotQueue",
)

QuickUpdating.$currentSnapshot
    .receive(on: snapshotQueue)
    .sink { [weak self] currentSnapshot in
        slowProcessing(currentSnapshot)
        updateUI()

    }
    .store(in: &cancellables)
```

Comment: Add those long running slow task in to a separate queue .

Comment: Combine's general solution to this problem is the backpressure mechanism (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/processing-published-elements-with-subscribers).   Is your producer a real-time producer, or could you drive production using backpressure from the consumer?  If real-time how will you prevent the producer from completely overwhelming the consumer?  Can you use parallelism in the processing stage to improve consumption performance?

Comment: @Yodagama Unfortunately this doesn't help as the producer is still much faster than the subscriber.

Comment: @ScottThompson The producer is real-time and there is no way to influence production from the consumer at the moment. There is also no way of preventing the producer from overwhelming the consumer. 

We might be able to batch multiple results together at the producer in a way that is faster than actual production. Which would then allow us to only react to new demand from the consumer by only adding demand after `update()` was successfully run.

Does this look like a feasable solution to you?

Comment: Possibly.  There is a built-in operator that allows you to collect by count, or you could write a custom publisher that listens upstream and collects items until something downstream makes a "demand" and then send all the items you've collected.

Comment: `collect` waits until the count is full though doesn't it? Which is not what we want.